# Android text and bitmap in menu items

Tags: android

In my app, I am creating a dynamic list of items using

```
shopsNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

// Create The Adapter

 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =     
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(ShopsListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shopsNameList);
```

I would like to have a text and an image in each element of the list, not a simple text.

I defined a listviewitem.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listitemimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"       
        android:src="@raw/shop" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and tried

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =     
new ArrayAdapter<String>(ShopsListActivity.this, R.layout.listviewitem, shopsNameList);
```

but my app crashes when I enter the list.

I am inside an activity creted with

```
 super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.shopslist);

  // Get the reference of ListView
  ListView shopsList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listShops);
  shopsNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
  shopElements = new ArrayList<ShopElement>();
```

Comment: You need to create custom adapter to be passed to listview. You can start here if you are new http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom adapter for your ListView:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List< String > objects)
    {
        super( context, R.layout.listviewitem, objects );

        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ShopListHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitem, parent, false);

            holder = new ShopListHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitemimage);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ShopListHolder )convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(getItem( position ));

        return convertView;
    }

    class ShopListHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```